# Plugin not found exception in Android app Development

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

**Faced this issue when trying to execute the friendly-eats step by step program provided by firebase**

Build file '/Users/shivarajcm/Projects/friendlyeats-android/build.gradle.kts' line: 4

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repositor

A solution to this problem on how i can sync back the project with the gradle files.